# How do we prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n!} = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

To prove the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}n^{2}}{n!}$$
converges, I could show the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{n^{2}}{n!}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
is decreasing. However, to prove
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n!}=0$$

Since for
$$a_{n}=\frac{n^{2}}{n!}$$
I have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=0$$
so, could I say that by the reason test, the sequence converges and therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Well done!

Alternatively, since we are dealing with limits at infinity, there is no harm to consider $n\geq 2$.

Having said that, notice that:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{n!} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{n(n - 1)}\frac{1}{(n - 2)!} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n - 1}\frac{1}{(n - 2)!} = 0.
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: OP is trying to show the series $\sum n^2/n!$ converges; knowing the general term goes to 0 is not sufficient.

Comment: @hunter the OP is trying to prove that the series $\sum (-1)^{n}n^{2}/n!$ converges. In order to do so, he is applying the [Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: gotcha didn't see the sign!